# WCF service hosted in a managed Windows service connect using a WCF service application

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Thank you in advance for any advice. I have a Windows service that is hosting a WCF service through `net.tcp` and this is working great. I have also created a WCF service application. I am trying to add the `net.tcp` service reference to the service application. Then I add it to the GAC that goes ok but if I try to RegAsm the WCF service application to allow it to be called from `Server.CreateObject` I get the error:

> Warning: Type library exporter encountered a type that derives from a
>   generic class and is not marked as
>   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]. Class interfaces cannot be
>   exposed for such types. Consider marking the type with
>   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] and exposing an explicit
>   interface as the default interface to COM using the
>   ComDefaultInterface attribute.

It does not work. I have tried to call it through a class library but this does not work either as the end point is not set correctly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Fixed this. Was a Permissions Error the iusr account did not have access to the web.config file from the WCF Service Application. So It works now. Now another problem has arised. I need to be able to call the WCF Service Application from asp classic but it does not use a web.config.